# How to make emacs scale when changing text-scaling-factor on gnome?

Tags: gnome, emacs

When I switch screen I do `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor $size`. All my programs are scaling correctly except for emacs (nothing change). I have to restart emacs each time (and only then it is scaled correctly) . What could I do ?

> Debian sid/gnome 42.0/wayland/Emacs 27.

Comment: The emacs.SE might have an answer for you: [Quickly adjusting Text to DPI changes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28390/quickly-adjusting-text-to-dpi-changes)

Comment: Thanks Marcus, but the answers look too complicated for me, and I refuse to spend time to hack for such a trivial things that ALL my other programs do correctly. Gnome is not a small and exotic DE... emacs should respond to text-scaling-factor without me having to hack stuff (I mean, if I were an emacs wizard I would hack that feature for everybody to use, but sadly I'm not). I ended up using [default-text-scale](https://github.com/purcell/default-text-scale), which it turns out is a nice and practical enough solution for me.

Comment: Well, there's one solution I knew of, all I can do is offer it to you! But thanks for referring me to that script

Comment: And that was very appreciated, no complain here :)